# Python read JSON files from all sub-directories

Tags: json, python-3.x, pandas

I have a following folder structure:

```
Directory    
    - Subdirectory 1:
       file.json
    - Subdirectory 2:
       file.json
    - Subdirectory 3:
       file.json
    - Subdirectory 4:
       file.json
```

How do I read these JSON files using Pandas?

Comment: Use `glob` module to get all json files and then iterate?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could do the following:

```
import glob, os
working_directory = os.getcwd()

sub_directories = [active_directory + "/" + x for x in os.listdir(working_directory) if os.path.isdir(active_directory + "/"+x)]
all_json_files = []

for sub_dir in sub_directories:
    os.chdir(sub_dir)
    for file in glob.glob("*.json"):
        all_json_files.append(sub_dir + "/" + file)

#Get back to original working directory
os.chdir(working_directory)

list_of_dfs = [pd.read_json(x) for x in all_json_files]
```

From there, if all json files have the same structure, you could concatenate them to get one single dataframe:

```
final_df = pd.concat(list_of_dfs)
```

Answer (score 12):

Try this code:

```
import pandas as pd
from pathlib import Path

files = Path("Directory").glob("**/*.json")

for file in files:
    df = pd.read_json(file)
```

To learn more about converting JSON string to Pandas object:

https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_json.html